# When are function arguments and return values constructed?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

I keep on reading about RVO and passing arguments by reference vs value. I get the idea: passing by reference is just syntactic sugar for passing a pointer, and passing by value calls the class's copy constructor to make a copy of the original object for the function to use. RVO avoids invoking a copy constructor for a function's return value.

What I am missing in my understanding is when exactly construction of arguments passed by value and objects returned by value occurs. What I assume is that objects passed by value are constructed on the stack just before the actual call and return value is copy constructed (in the absence of RVO) just before returning. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumtions are pretty much correct.  For pass by value, the
object is constructed in the location where parameters are
normally passed, sometime before the function is called (but
after the previous statement), and are destructed before
returning from the function, as if they were local variables in
the function.  For pass by reference, the object is constructed
on the stack (or wherever temporaries are normally constructed),
and destructed at the end of the full expression.  For return
values, the object is constructed by the called function, in the
return statement (but before the destructors of local variables
are called), and destructed by the callee, at the end of the
full expression.

Comment: _For pass by reference, the object is constructed on the stack (or wherever temporaries are normally constructed), and destructed at the end of the full expression._ What do you mean by that? Using _pass-by-reference_ normally doesn't call a constructor.

Comment: @MWid Exactly what it says.  Most compilers construct temporaries on the stack, along with local variables, but there's no requirement that this be the case.  But a temporary which will be passed by reference will be constructed where ever the compiler usually constructs its temporaries.

Comment: @JamesKanze on x86 in particular, how are class objects returned? Obviously, you can't fit much in `eax` (or `rax`).

Is this material for a whole separate question?

Comment: @mebob The usual solution, x86 or not, is for the caller to allocate a temporary locally, and pass a pointer with its address as a hidden first parameter.  (I've heard that some compilers will sometimes put a class that fits in a register, but only under certain restricted conditions.)

Comment: @JamesKanze OK. Is that the kind of thing that would be dictated by an ABI?

Comment: @mebob It's defined by the ABI, although a compiler could do things differently when both the callee and the caller are compiled with the same compiler.  (Most platforms don't have a standard C++ ABI anyway, so the compiler can do what it wants for C++.)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : yes

Long answer: yes, see the asm for more details :D

Additionnal info: The order of evaluation of the parameters depends on you compiler

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you are right.

There is a weird concept of "Return Value Elision" or "Copy Elision". Essentially, some compilers are smart enough to see you are returning by value, and will do it all in place (in certain situations, I havn't found any compiler does it reliably enough that either RHR or Return Value Optimization isn't super helpful).

Essentially:

```
std::vector<int> foo();
std::vector<int> bar = foo();
```

*May* actually use the memory of location of bar inside as the return value.

http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

So it can happen. I never trust it...

Comment: "I haven't found any compiler does it reliabley": Visual Studios does it systematically any time there's only one `return` in the function (which means any time the function is well written).

Comment: @JamesKanze Yeah, I'm probably just paranoid about it, I have the general sentiment of the author of the article :-/. It is annoying to trust the compiler to do this for high performance applications. I just start asking myself, What if I need to add a different return statement later? what if I make it into a virtual function? What if I need to call it via a function pointer? I sleep better at night passing in a reference, even if it is silly. :-P

Comment: ...Or using C++11, cuz move constructors are awesome, get the above when you can or get lightweight copies when you can't.

Comment: For input arguments, pass by reference is fairly usual for class types.  The copy elision you're talking about concerns the return values, and it more or less universal.

Comment: @JamesKanze Right, I meant pass-by-reference as apposed to return by value. aka `void foo(std::vector<int>* return)` instead of `std::vector<int> foo()`. "universal" implies you can trust it to happen every time, which as I stated you may be able to but (imho) i don't: the cost of the copy is usually too high when it doesn't, its allowed but not guaranteed under the standard, and its a pain in the butt to find it when it doesn't do it. In C++11, it doesn't matter cuz when it isn't elided it does a move, so the penalty is much lower.

Comment: Aren't return value optimizations and copy elision pretty much obsolete now, with the introduction of C++11 move semantics? I mean, obviously, pre-C++11 code won't have move constructors, but from C++11 on there isn't much of a point is there? Or am I mistaken.

Comment: @mebob Not doing any operation is more performant than moving :)

Comment: @Drax Also, moving must be explicitly programmed, or it doesn't happen.

Comment: @JamesKanze I'm not sure i understand what is meant by "_explicitly programmed_"

Comment: @Drax It means that you have to provide a move constructor for it to work.

Comment: @Drax That's true but hopefully a move constructor will be near negligible.

Comment: @JamesKanze If i'm not wrong their is a default move constructor genereated by the compiler as long as you don't have a specific copy semantic (eg. as long as you don't provide a copy constructor), so even if you don't explicitly provide a move constructor you should have one in 95% cases.

Comment: @mebob "Negligible" is relative, copy elision will never be completely not useful in C++: you *have* to copy a ton of stuff from one memory space to another if you don't. Basically, even if you have a move constuctor, you have to copy `sizeof(class A)` if not elided (including VTables, RTTI, ect!). What C++11 does is make it so the penalty for copy elision not happening much smaller, which allows you to ignore it unless it becomes a problem ("The root of all evil is premature optimization" "But we still have to optimize")

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Point taken. I wasn't really thinking of the case of having lots of non-pointer members in the class, which must even be copied in a move-constructor, so that is a good point.

Comment: @Drax A move constructor is not generated if any of the bases or members do not have a move constructor.  Which means that unless you systematically provide a move constructor for all of your classes, most will not be movable.

Comment: @JamesKanze Unless you provided a specific copy constructor for your base classes, there is no reason these base classes won't have a default move constructor :)